# How to load smaller and faster images with java servlet?

Tags: java, image, servlets

I'm developing a web application using GWT from Google. Currently I upload the image to the web server and save the image using a java servlet:

```
for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
    String fileName = item.getName();

    File file = new File("imagePath");

    item.write(file);
}
```

After that I only have to provide the image URL to show it on browser.

Unfortunately this is poor solution to my problem since this specific web application loads several preview images (product catalog) per page.

Is there any way to load a smaller version of the saved image to the client when presenting the preview images (as you see on when you search images on Google)?

Comment: You can provide different URLs for preview images. Where is a problem?

Comment: @Andrei Yes I know but I wanted to have only one image that I would compress/shrink before loading to the client (in case of preview) and load the full image only when the user asks for it.

Comment: @belyid Then this is not related to GWT. You'll have better chances of getting a good answer if you remove GWT from the equation (and question) and update your tags; maybe add [tag:servlets] to begin with (and remove [tag:gwt])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be done on a server side.

For example, you may request an image with an option `?size=preview`, which will instruct your servlet to retrieve an image with a specified id or name and resize it to a preview size before returning to the client.

UPDATE:

As Jeroen suggested, and I totally agree, saving two versions of a file - preview and full - is the way to go, especially if you show images frequently. As an additional benefit, browsers will be able to cache both the preview and the full image.

Comment: Is that a better option than save several versions of the same image with different sizes and upload a small or normal as needed?

Comment: I would personally save a smaller version for the previews and a full resolution version of the image on the server. Resizing can be done once automatically when uploading (see the Java 2D libraries for this), but resizing every time an image is loaded will have an impact on server performance.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter: I totally agree, and I updated my answer to reflect your comments.